# Aspose Slide taking significant time while initializing/instantiating

Tags: java, aspose

I am using Aspose Slide library for java. It is taking significant amount of time to initialize it's Presentation class.

For single slide presentation also it is taking around **5 seconds**.
But if we run the code twice, on second attempt it takes considerably less time i.e. around 1 second.

`Presentation pres = new Presentation("file.ppt");`

Used version is: `aspose-slides-17.7-jdk16.jar`

System Configuration: `Processor: Core i3, RAM: 6 GB; OS: Ubuntu`

Is there any way to make it fast ?

Answer (score 0):

I have observed the requirements shared by and like to share that when you instantiate Presentation object for first time, it loads Aspose.Slides DOM(Document Object Model) in memory which includes larger number of classes internally and takes some time. This only takes place once and when you load the same or other presentation again using API, It shall take considerably less amount of time. This is implementation behaviour of API and we are also working on further improvement of API performance as well. I hope this will be understandable.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Many Thanks,